# Python-fu script not showing in Gimp menu

Tags: python, gimp, gimpfu, python-fu

I’ve been at [Gimp: python script not showing in menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334993/gimp-python-script-not-showing-in-menu) and it didn’t help me. Here’s what I tried, step by step:

**1.** I’m running Gimp 2.8.16 on Mac OS X 10.9.5 from the command line with `gimp` as my `.bashrc` file includes

```
alias gimp='/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/MacOS/GIMP --verbose --console-messages '
```

I look at the terminal output, I see lots of messages but nothing pops out as a problem (do you want the dump here?). I see right at the start `Enabling internal Python...` so that should be good.

**2.** Filters > Python-Fu > Console brings up the console, with

```
GIMP 2.8.16 Python Console
Python 2.7.8 (default, Dec  5 2015, 09:38:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]
>>>
```

—so, once again, python seems to be working.

**3.** Because of [this tip here](http://gimpchat.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=12145#p164633) I tried running a Python script. I opened an image and ran Filters > Render > Clouds > Fog. Works like a charm – in the console I do get a few type conversion warnings when the window is fired up:

```
** (foggify.py:30312): WARNING **: Trying to register gtype 'GMountMountFlags' as enum when in fact it is of type 'GFlags'
** (foggify.py:30312): WARNING **: Trying to register gtype 'GDriveStartFlags' as enum when in fact it is of type 'GFlags'
** (foggify.py:30312): WARNING **: Trying to register gtype 'GSocketMsgFlags' as enum when in fact it is of type 'GFlags'
```

I searched my computer and foggify.py is actually in `/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/foggify.py` so this proves that Python is working, but not that it’s loading scripts. I’m a little confused as `foggify.py` only has 77 lines, not 30312.

**4.** GIMP > Preferences > Folders > Scripts shows GIMP should load the following directories for scripts:

```
/Users/julio/Library/Application Support/GIMP/2.8/scripts
/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/share/gimp/2.0/scripts
```

I’m not using `/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/share/gimp/2.0/scripts` but it has a lot of `*.scm` files (so, probably all in Scheme). I never added anything here myself.

**5.** I only have a single script: `ls -l "/Users/julio/Library/Application Support/Gimp/2.8/scripts"` yields

```
total 8
-rwxr-xr-x  1 julio  staff  654 25 Jun 16:25 minimal.py
```

(nothing else)

**6.** Here’s my `minimal.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from gimpfu import *

def minimal():
    pass

register(
    "python_fu_minimal",                                    # plugin name
    "Minimal plug-in example",                              # blurb (short description)
    "Show the smallest possible Python plug-in example",    # help (long description)
    "Michael Schumacher",                                   # author
    "Michael Schumacher",                                   # copyright info
    "2007",                                                 # date
    "<Image>/Tools/Minimal",                                # menu position and label
    None,                                                   # image types accepted
    [],                                                     # input parameters
    [],                                                     # output (results)
    minimal                                                 # method to call
    )

main()
```

**7.** I run `gimp` with `minimal.py` *already* in the `scripts` directory indicated above, and I can’t see any “Minimal” item in the “Tools” menu.

I also tried the variation below, which didn’t work either:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from gimpfu import *

def minimal():
    pass

register(
    "python_fu_minimal",                                    # plugin name
    "Minimal plug-in example",                              # blurb (short description)
    "Show the smallest possible Python plug-in example",    # help (long description)
    "Michael Schumacher",                                   # author
    "Michael Schumacher",                                   # copyright info
    "2007",                                                 # date
    "Minimal",                                              # menu position and label
    None,                                                   # image types accepted
    [],                                                     # input parameters
    [],                                                     # output (results)
    minimal,                                                # method to call
    menu="<Image>/Tools"
    )

main()
```

Comment: welcome to GIMP scripting. If you check the GIMP answers in my profile you will find a couple more hints (maybe more than on the documentation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python "scripts" are technically "plug-ins" and should therefore be in the "plug-ins" subdirectory (/Users/julio/Library/Application Support/GIMP/2.8/plug-ins).

Update for 2.10: Gimp 2.10 still supports the 2.8 way, with `.py` files put in the `plug-ins` directory but it also supports the new style where the `.py` (actually the main plugin executable) is in a sub-directory of `plug-ins` that bears the same name, together with other files it might need, if any. AFAIK this will be the only accepted way in future Gimp versions.

```
{Your Gimp profile}
└── plug-ins
    ├── some_2.08_plugin.py
    ├── another_2.08_plugin.py
    ├── some_plugin_for_2.10_and_beyond
    │   ├── some_plugin_for_2.10_and_beyond.py
    │   └── some_python_module.py
    └── another_plugin_for_2.10_and_beyond
        ├── another_plugin_for_2.10_and_beyond.py
        └── another_auxiliary_file.dat
```

Comment: **Thank you** @xenoid, you just saved my life. I was at this for _four hours_ yesterday, if you can believe that.
When starting Gimp via the command line, it now shows it’s going through the script:
`Querying plug-in: '/Users/julio/Library/Application Support/GIMP/2.8/plug-ins/minimal.py'`